# What is an mbinator?

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory

I see plenty of mentions of their categorical dual, i.e. co-mbinators like y-combinator, etc. But no one seems to give an example of an mbinator? Even wiki.haskell.org/Combinator doesn't mention it.

Comment: I've never heard of an "mbinator" before. It's not even an English word. Where did you hear about it?

Comment: Also, combinators don't have a categorical dual.

Comment: @AaditMShah Generally a "co-something" is the dual of a "something". Therefore a "co-mbinator" must be the dual of an "mbinator". It's a pun, a joke question.

Answer (score 1):

The [etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/combine) doesn't involve "co-".  I guess you could ask about "binator", which might make pairs without putting them together.  But that's not a very useful concept.